# Scaling bug with multi-touch Canvas scale with pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, konvajs

Using the sample code from Konvajs.org as a base (https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Multi-touch_Scale_Stage.html), I have added a large SVG to a layer (4096 x 3444) to experiment with zoom / pan of a vector-based map, base64 encoded SVG in this instance. Initial impressions are good however during testing I experience an odd bug where during a pinch the view of the map would snap to a different location on the map not the area that I centred on.

Here is the code (map base64 code removed due to length):

```
// by default Konva prevent some events when node is dragging
// it improve the performance and work well for 95% of cases
// we need to enable all events on Konva, even when we are dragging a node
// so it triggers touchmove correctly
Konva.hitOnDragEnabled = true;

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height,
  draggable: true,
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();

var triangle = new Konva.RegularPolygon({
  x: 190,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  sides: 3,
  radius: 80,
  fill: 'green',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4,
});

var circle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 380,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  radius: 70,
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4,
});

let bg = new Konva.Image({
    width: 4096,
    height: 3444
});
layer.add(bg);

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    bg.image(image);
    layer.draw();
};

image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,...';

function getDistance(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2));
}

function getCenter(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: (p1.x + p2.x) / 2,
    y: (p1.y + p2.y) / 2,
  };
}
var lastCenter = null;
var lastDist = 0;

stage.on('touchmove', function (e) {
  e.evt.preventDefault();
  var touch1 = e.evt.touches[0];
  var touch2 = e.evt.touches[1];

  if (touch1 && touch2) {
    // if the stage was under Konva's drag&drop
    // we need to stop it, and implement our own pan logic with two pointers
    if (stage.isDragging()) {
      stage.stopDrag();
    }

    var p1 = {
      x: touch1.clientX,
      y: touch1.clientY,
    };
    var p2 = {
      x: touch2.clientX,
      y: touch2.clientY,
    };

    if (!lastCenter) {
      lastCenter = getCenter(p1, p2);
      return;
    }
    var newCenter = getCenter(p1, p2);

    var dist = getDistance(p1, p2);

    if (!lastDist) {
      lastDist = dist;
    }

    // local coordinates of center point
    var pointTo = {
      x: (newCenter.x - stage.x()) / stage.scaleX(),
      y: (newCenter.y - stage.y()) / stage.scaleX(),
    };

    var scale = stage.scaleX() * (dist / lastDist);

    stage.scaleX(scale);
    stage.scaleY(scale);

    // calculate new position of the stage
    var dx = newCenter.x - lastCenter.x;
    var dy = newCenter.y - lastCenter.y;

    var newPos = {
      x: newCenter.x - pointTo.x * scale + dx,
      y: newCenter.y - pointTo.y * scale + dy,
    };

    stage.position(newPos);

    lastDist = dist;
    lastCenter = newCenter;
  }
});

stage.on('touchend', function () {
  lastDist = 0;
  lastCenter = null;
});


layer.add(triangle);
layer.add(circle);
stage.add(layer);
```

I am unsure if this is due to the large size of the image and / or canvas or an inherent flaw in the example code from Konvas.js. This has been tested, with the same results, on 2 models of iPad Pro, iPhone X & 11, Android Pixel 3, 5 and 6 Pro.

Here is the code on codepen as an example: https://codepen.io/mr-jose/pen/WNXgbdG

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi Jose - that's a well written question for a new contributor.  I can't answer your question specifically, but I wanted to mention that with use-cases like maps with heavy zoom-in-and-out there is usually a tiling approach in use whereby a zoom-in might causes another 'deeper' image to load into the viewer, thus giving the level of detail the user expects as a payoff for zooming. So what I'm saying is that ultimately you might want to consider that in your follow-on dev on the project. Otherwise I'm interested to see the answer too!

Comment: Thanks @VanquishedWombat I actually tried that approach with exactly the same results. I split a map into 16 1028 x 1028 and 2048 x 2048 png tiles. The size of the tiles had no perceivable impact.

Comment: Hi @Jose. Were you able to solve this problem? If so could you please share?

Comment: @MykhailoK. the solution from andy203 works a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue and discovered that it was caused by the dragging functionality of the stage. Everytime `if (stage.isDragging())` evaluated to true, the jump happened.

For me what worked was setting draggable to false while pinch zooming and back to true on touch end.

```js
stage.on('touchmove', function (e) {
  ...
  if (touch1 && touch2) {
    stage.draggable(false);
    ....
  }
});

stage.on('touchend', function (e) {
  ...
  stage.draggable(true);
});
```